# In scene builder, i am adding css file and facing the following issue: css file is not implemented and displayed

Tags: java, css, javafx, project, scenebuilder

I've added css file but it didn't work in scene builder. My expectation is to display the css file implementation in scene builder:

```
. gradient{
-fx-backcolor-linearback (in right bottom #89092,#82229);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have couple of issues:

1. CSS property `-fx-backcolor-linearback` doesn't exist in JavaFX CSS. Instead, you can use the `-fx-background-color` property to set the background color.
2. check for syntax errors in values for the background color in your code.
3. let's say you are trying to set a gradient background color in JavaFX using CSS, you can write the code as following:

   ```
   .gradient {-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #89092, #82229);}
   ```